# Android: How to send extra from an activity to a child activity of a fragment?

Tags: android, fragment

I want to send extras through Intent from an Activity to a child Activity of a FragmentActivity? How can I achieve that? 
The thing is, I need to startActivity the FragmentActivity, while the extras need to be passed to its child Activity.

Thanks

Comment: There is no concept in Android of "a child Activity of a FragmentActivity".